# DirectX 11 Append Buffer Byte Width

Tags: c++, append, directx-11

When you set up a buffer to use as an append buffer, is the ByteWidth element of the buffer description the initial size (before appending anything) or the maximum size it is allowed to reach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I have deduced that it is in fact the initial size and not the maximum.

IMPORTANT Edit: What I deduced was completely wrong. What it actually does is define the maximum limit. Anything appended above and beyond this limit is automatically dropped by the shader.